# How to add width & height (resolution) on wordpress function?

Tags: theme-customizer

How to add Custom width & Height
to our custom image uploader

```
function clientPic6( $wp_customize ) {   
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'client_background_img_6'); // Add setting for logo uploader
    // Add control for logo uploader (actual uploader)
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'm1_client_img_6', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Client Image', 'm2_C6' ),
        'section'  => 'custom_client_block',
        'settings' => 'client_background_img_6',
    ) ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'clientPic6' );
```

Comment: You mean you want to allow only images of a certain size to be uploaded? Or you want fields for the height and width, so the client can set them?

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for `WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control` which has `width` and `height` parameters (along with `flex_width` and `flex_height`). This will then present you with the image dimensions when you select an image in the Customizer. For example, [refer to how the Custom Logo control is registered in core](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/4.7.4/src/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L3787-L3804):

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'custom_logo', array(
    'label'         => __( 'Logo' ),
    'section'       => 'title_tagline',
    'priority'      => 8,
    'height'        => $custom_logo_args[0]['height'],
    'width'         => $custom_logo_args[0]['width'],
    'flex_height'   => $custom_logo_args[0]['flex-height'],
    'flex_width'    => $custom_logo_args[0]['flex-width'],
    'button_labels' => array(
        'select'       => __( 'Select logo' ),
        'change'       => __( 'Change logo' ),
        'remove'       => __( 'Remove' ),
        'default'      => __( 'Default' ),
        'placeholder'  => __( 'No logo selected' ),
        'frame_title'  => __( 'Select logo' ),
        'frame_button' => __( 'Choose logo' ),
    ),
) ) );
```

Comment: yes but how to to add this in my code

Comment: @M.Nadeem I added the example for how the control is used in core for the custom logo control.